# How to display data in template from Vue.extend?

Tags: vue.js

Here is my code:

```js
   var guestContent = Vue.extend({
       template: `
           <p>Guest content</p>
       `,
       data: function () {
           return {
              qs: getQuestionsContent();  // here I would like to get in qs data from function          
           }    
       }
   });
```

Here is my App.js:

```js
    App = new Vue ({ /
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            topMenuView: "guestmenu",
            contentView: "guestcontent",
        }
    });
```

I need to display `qs` instead of Guest content and do for example `v-for` or some kind of other iteration. How can I do it?

Why:

```js
    var guestContent = Vue.extend({
        template: `
            <p>Guest content</p>
            <p>{{foo}}</p> // foo not display
        `,
        data: function () {   
            foo: "dddddddddd";
        }
    });
```

Why is this not working?

Comment: I am trying to get data from function in `Vue.extend` and then to display it's content in `template`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

**html**

```html
    <body>
      <guest-content></guest-content>
    </body>

    <template id="guest-content-template">
    Guest Content
      <ul>
        <li v-for="question in questions">
      {{question}}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </template>
```

**js**

```js
    var guestContent = Vue.extend({
    template: "#guest-content-template",
        data: function (){
          return {
             questions: []
          }
        },
        ready(){
            this.getQuestionsContent();
        },
        methods:{
            getQuestionsContent(){
                this.questions = [
                    "Why?",
                  "What?",
                  "When?"
                ];
            }
        }
    });
        
    Vue.component('guest-content',guestContent);
        
    new Vue({
      el:'body'
    });
```

Anything in a `{{}}` is assumed to be within the current Vue scope, so you just use `foo` or `questions` not `guestContent.foo`.

The `data` attribute is a function that has to return the data for the app.  If you don't return anything, the component wont have any data.

Comment: and what I should write at html? If it's component should I call it like `{{guestContent.foo}}`. And could you explain what this code will do without return?

Comment: `data` is only declaration and attributes in it can't be assigned in data function? And what about `methods`? Can I assign attributes from it to data?

Comment: could you add comments, or explain what `data`, `ready()` and `methods` do. I read vue docs, but do not understand how to use them...

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: response is not defined`

Comment: @user1432751 You need to write the `getQuestionsContent()` yourself as I showed in the comments.  I added a couple more comments.

Comment: I do not get any errors, but nothings is display https://jsfiddle.net/huo1ad11/
Is there any other way to call function to get data to variable instead of putting it's in `methods`?

Comment: @user1432751 I got a lot of errors trying to use your fiddle... look at this version https://jsfiddle.net/7q2t5khn/2/ . You can use `this.$http` to fetch your data in the real one, I just mocked data for the fiddle

Comment: @user1432751 even better, use a separate html block for templates: https://jsfiddle.net/7q2t5khn/3/

Comment: And could you edit your answer to help more people easy find answer without reading all this comments?

Comment: @user1432751 those will both work, you just need to have the global `Vue` available if you are going to call `Vue.http`.  Also need to make sure to include `vue-resource` either way